# How to map modified, not matching the destination, source value, using the model mapper?

Tags: java, reusability, modelmapper

I have two API entities (`EntityA` and `EntityB`) that implement `BaseEntity`.
Both entities have the nullable parameter `identifier`.

```
@Value
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
public class EntityA implements BaseEntity {
    String identifier;
...
}
```

```
@Value
@Builder(builderClassName = "Builder")
public class EntityB implements BaseEntity {
    String identifier;
...
}
```

I have POJO as well with `externalId` parameter. This field value should include the prefix of 4 characters of the source's identifier.

```
@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Pojo {
    private String externalId;
    ...
}
```

I want to map the APIs values to existing POJO `PojoEntity`, using `ModelMapper`. However,

1. source getter and destination setter are not match.
2. source's value should be modified.

I can set the value post-factum, on an already mapped POJO.

```
public Pojo mapEntityAToPojo(EntityA entity, Pojo pojo) {
    modelMapper.map(entity, pojo);
    Optional.ofNullable(entity.getIdentifier()).ifPresent(
            identifier -> pojo.setExternalId(getIdentifierAlphaNumericPrefix(identifier)));
    return pojo;
}

public Pojo mapEntityBToPojo(EntityB entity, Pojo pojo) {
    modelMapper.map(entity, pojo);
    Optional.ofNullable(entity.getIdentifier()).ifPresent(
            identifier -> pojo.setExternalId(getIdentifierAlphaNumericPrefix(identifier)));
    return pojo;
}

private String getIdentifierAlphaNumericPrefix(String identifier) {
    return identifier.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").substring(0, 4);
}
```

But I'm sure, there is a more elegant way, to configure model mapper.
Any suggestions?